# wp_mail is not working in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using wp_mail function, but it is not working in loop. Below is my code that i used

```
$productName = '';
$productName = implode(',',$users_arr[$i]['productName']);
$productId = '';
$productId .= implode(',',$users_arr[$i]['productId']);
require('wp-load.php');
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
$to = $users_arr[$i]['userEmail'];

$subject = 'You have won the auction!';
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

$message = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\">\r\n
<head>\r\n
<title>Hello Test</title>\r\n
</head>\r\n
<body>\r\n
<p></p>\r\n
<p>Congratulations, You have won the auction for ".$productName." and <a href=".$cart_url."?add-to-cart=".$productId." target='_blank'>Pay now</a></p>\r\n
</body>\r\n
</html>";
echo $to;
$mail = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
// wp_trash_post();
sleep(10);
echo 'done ---->'.$mail;
```

`

This is my code that I used in `for` loop. I have different email id and each mail id have different message,but in loop mail can't be work.

Comment: Show all the code not just a snippet.

Comment: Hi, I mentioned all code and but did not add only for loop,

Comment: If you don't show all the code I can't help.  You might have an issue with the loop.

Comment: I found the issue where it is . but I canot find the solution. the issue is mail won't send when there is a dynamic URL in the body. `<a href=".$cart_url."?add-to-cart=".$productId." target='_blank'>Pay now</a>`

Comment: There is main issue in message body. can you suggest me relevant solution for it ?

Comment: Why would it care if there's a URL being sent in the email?

Comment: Url is dynamic and it is necessary to send with mail.